# Failed to establish a Tor connection. Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed. None of the answers work read below for more please

Tags: bridge, connection

Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.

Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed And adress and port changes all the time

I tried All the bridges, obs4, obs3, meek, fte and even tried to use this custom ones

I read about http or mmi attacks (i cant say them properly) and stuff but their solutions dont work either.
I checked firewall and time and

I am very inexperienced and all i do is read if you read this please explain it to me in simple terms. Please Respond I love Tor and i cant bear to not use it

Thank You Very Much :)

Comment: Can you provide some log output and when you retreived custom bridges, did you make sure to get obfs4 bridges?

Comment: Umm too long by 6349 words for log output. how much would you like? and yes i got the obs4 bridges

Comment: Maybe about the last 10 minutes or so of logs?